# Element showing if placed in master but not in view - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Okay so I've just gotten round to learning Laravel and I've hit a problem...

I have a template page in the _master folder called regular_template.blade.php I have my standard home.blade.php in the view and HomeController.php in the controllers

in the home.blade.php file I have this

```
@extends("_master.regular_template")

@section("content")

<div id="top-bar"></div>

@stop
```

but for some reason when it is in the view file it won't show on the screen but it shows if in master page, this is the route I have

```
Route::get("", "HomeController@getIndex");
Route::controller("home", "HomeController");
```

and in the homecontroller page I have this...

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    protected $layout = "_master.regular_template";
    protected $restful = true;

    public function getIndex() {
        $this->layout->title = "Homepage";
        $this->layout->content = View::make("home");
    }

    public function missingMethod($parameters) {
        return "404";
    }
 }
```

Does anybody know why this is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your regular_template file look like? Does it contain a @yield('content')?

Comment: @JoelHinz well now don't I feel stupid! haha thank you that was the problem :)

Comment: one advice. don't use controller layout and blade layout. it is bound to disaster later. pick one and stick to it.

Comment: Hehe, we've all been there, haven't we? :) Glad you got it working!